# UITableView checkmark & sections

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am making a `UITableView` that allows cells to be selected (like the languanges `TableView\, but once one) but the checkmark accessory isn't working.

```
if (tableView == self.numberTableView) {
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.text = [arryNumber objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        if (inumberfont == 0) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }
    if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        if (inumberfont == 1) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }
    if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"2"])
    {
        if (inumberfont == 2) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }
    if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"3"])
    {
        if (inumberfont == 3) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }
    if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"4"])
    {
        if (inumberfont == 4) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Is `arryNumber` an array containing @"0", @"1", @"2", @"3" and @"4"?

Comment: Yes, I just didnt copy all the tableview, beacuse is very big, like 8 arrays ;)

Comment: You should learn to use switch statements… a lot better ;)

Comment: @Kristian He doesn't even need a switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your code.

```
if (tableView == self.numberTableView) {
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row];
    if (inumberfont == indexPath.row) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

The above code does the exact same thing as your code, but well, your code wasn't working. In the following code I've fixed the errors I spotted. I also added some missing code. If you had it before, but didn't include it, that's fine; I just wanted to make sure that it wasn't missing.

```
if (tableView == self.numberTableView) {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NumberCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row];
    if (inumberfont == indexPath.row) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "the checkmark accessory isn't work", but try improving your code with my suggestions and if it still doesn't work, drop a comment and I'll see what I can do to help you further.

**EDIT:** Found out what the problem was. Try the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    inumberfont = indexPath.row;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to say that the code work, the problem is that the checkmark just appear when I open the app again, and I need that the checkmark is Instant, by the way thanks a lot for the help...

Comment: Don't you think it would be a good idea to mention what the problem is in the question?

Comment: By the way have you noticed the check marks on stack overflow? It seems like you've failed to click them. When you've gotten an answer that answered your question or solved your problem you click on the check mark right next to that answer. This will let everyone know that this answer is the correct one and you and the guy that kindly helped you will gain reputation. If you have questions about it feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot... do you have paypal ?

Answer (score 1):

What is the line:

```
cell.text = [arryNumber objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

What is `cell.text`? Don't you mean `cell.textLabel.text`

By the way I think you could probably condense your code by doing:

```
if ([cell.textLabel.text intValue] == inumberfont) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

You wouldn't need all 8 if statements just that one.

Comment: The problem is that that a have another cell(called "size") and this cell have a uislider, so I need the checkmark ONLY in some cell(0,1,2,3,4) by the way thanks for the help...

Comment: In that case just the first part of my answer should work. You could always surround my second chunk of code in an if statement to account for the slider.